# How does one reset the coordinates for panzoom.js?

Tags: html, video, zooming, pan

I'm working on an HTML/css/js program to drag a video to position it and zoom it with the mouse wheel. The program zooms fine in browser screen. But, when I change to full screen, the video creeps up from the cursor when zooming in. How does one reset the coordinates for panzoom.js when going to full screen?

These are the links: [Zoom.html](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://rawgit.com/JamminHTML5/Zoom/master/Zoom) and [jquery.panzoom.js](https://rawgit.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom/master/dist/jquery.panzoom.js)

Comment: The Zoom.html program is designed for Chrome. It doesn't work in IE. The link given in the question is for screen view. Here's the html source code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JamminHTML5/Zoom/master/Zoom

Comment: does not work on firefox either you should may be use an other alternative script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an 'reset' option in [jquery.panzoom.js](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom). So when going full screen, add this to your `BigSmall` function:

```
$('#focal').find('.panzoom').panzoom("reset");
```

It will then reset the zoom state.

Comment: You worked hard for the 100 bonus points, didn't you? You ran the program, & dug into the functions. Your effort is greatly appreciated. Hope you enjoy panning & zooming your own videos!